# DateTime in android

Tags: android, datetime

I've been looking for something and its not clear, but the answer should be.

I'm working on an app using the phone's locale time.

If I just use `DateTime.now()` to get the current time, do I get the time of the current timezone the phone is in (assuming this is auto-updated on the phone) or the current time of the phones origin locale??

So if the phone's locale is say Germany (GMT+1) at 14:25 and using my app I travel to Portugal (GMT), the time on my phone will update to GMT 13:25 when I cross into Portugal, and time goes back an hour.

So when my service looks for the current time with

```
  DateTime CurrentHomeTime=DateTime.Now()
```

what time will CurrentHomeTime say?? 13:25 for the current country's timezone, or 14:25 for the origin locale of the phone??

Comment: Have you tried chaging the locale on your phone? I would guess you could test (fake) traveling to other timezones?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you would use the Time class in order to get the current time:

Time now = new Time();

now.setToNow();

The default constructor above will use the current time zone.
You can also initialize to another time zone if you like:

Time now = new Time("GMT")

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html